# Why didn't K9 win vs AA with K9 on flop

Tags: texas-hold-em

In Zynga poker sit and go: 25k starter

Villain dealt AA
I'm dealt K9

Villain goes all in 25k
I call 25k (all in as well)

Dealer flops K-7-9-x-7 (x isn't relevant and I don't remember what it was atm)

Zynga poker says Villain wins With AA-77 and I'm sent packing. Why doesn't my K9 beat him?

Answer (score 1):

In no limit hold 'em you can pick 5 cards out of the 2 in your hand and the 5 on the board to make your hand. Villain has two pair, aces and sevens. Hero has two pair, kings and nines. If multiple players have two pair then: the highest pair is compared first, then the lower pair, then the kicker. Villain has a higher pair then hero, therefore villain wins.

Comment: So if the second sevin doesn't come up, I have two pairs KK 99 and win, correct?

Comment: @enorl76 the second seven? Yes then you win, because your opponent only has one pair of aces against your two pair.